# Discord JS member.ban not deleting messages

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I've recently been setting up a member.ban for bot accounts, like the invite links accounts, but everytime I run member.ban, it bans them but doesn't delete any messages (being join message or any messages sent) Is there a way to add an amount of time for deleting message history (like manual bans?)

```
// ./events/guildMemberAdd.js

if (member.user.username.includes("discord.gg")) {
  member.ban("Account being a bot.")
    .then(() => console.log(`Banned ${member.displayName}, ${m}`))
    .catch(console.error);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument in ban method (if it's an integer) determine how many days of message you want to delete (max 7),

```
member.ban(7) // will delete messages in the last 7 days by that user.
```

If it is a string, you add a reason for banning. If you want both you'll have to pass the object with properties `days` and `reason`.

```
member.ban({days:7,reason:"Trolling!"}) // will delete messages in last 7 days and add reason
```

---

Update for DiscordJS version 14.13.0 and onwards:

The ban function accepts a [BanOptions](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/14.13.0/typedef/BanOptions) object type that contains

```js
deleteMessageSeconds : integer
reason : string
```

For example to ban a member and delete a weeks worth of messages, use this code:

```js
// Ban a guild member, deleting a week's worth of messages
guildMember.ban({ deleteMessageSeconds: 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, reason: 'They deserved it' })
  .then(() => console.log(`Banned ${member.displayName}, ${m}`))
  .catch(console.error);
```